# How do I extract text from multiple HTML files and output it into one CSV?

Tags: python, html, csv

I am trying to extract certain texts based on surrounding words/patterns and output the information to a file called sample.csv.

For example, I have a directory of files:

file1.html
file2.html
file3.html

Each file contains the following structure. For example, file1.html:

```
<strong>Hello world</strong>

<p><strong>Name:</strong> John Smith</p>
<p>Some text</p>

<p><strong>Location</strong></p>

<blockquote>
<p>122 Main Street &amp; City, ST 12345 &gt;</p>
</blockquote>
<p>Some text</p>
```

Based on the above HTML structure, I want to output it to a sample.csv file that looks like this:

```
filename,name,location
file1.html,John Smith,122 Main Street
file2.html,Mary Smith,123 North Road
file3.html,Kate Lee,90 Winter Lane
```

I have the following python code:

```
import os
import csv
import re

csv_cont = []
directory = os.getcwd()
for root,dir,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:

        if file.endswith(".html"):
            f = open(file, 'r')
            
            name = re.search('<p><strong>Name:</strong>(.*)</p>', f)
            
            location = re.search('<p><strong>Location</strong></p><blockquote><p>(.*)&amp;', f)

            tmp = []
            tmp.append(file)
            tmp.append(name)
            
            tmp.append(location)

            csv_cont.append(tmp)    
            f.close()


#Change name of test.csv to whatever you want
with open("sample.csv", 'w', newline='') as myfile:
     wr = csv.DictWriter(myfile, fieldnames = ["filename", "name", "location"], delimiter = ',')
     wr.writeheader()
     wr = csv.writer(myfile)
     wr.writerows(csv_cont)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: You probably need `s = f.read()` and then do the searches against `s`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be parsing html using regular expressions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags  Use a proper parser instead.

Comment: @pavel -- I updated my code to reflect the use of a parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the file and run search against it. Replace

```
f = open(file, 'r')
name = re.search('<p><strong>Name:</strong>(.*)</p>', f)
            
location = re.search('<p><strong>Location</strong></p><blockquote><p>(.*)&amp;', f)
```

with

```
f = open(file, 'r')
file_content = f.read()
name = re.search('<p><strong>Name:</strong>(.*)</p>', file_content).group(1)
location = re.search('<p><strong>Location</strong></p>\n\n<blockquote>\n<p>(.*)&amp', file_content).group(1)
```

Corrected:
Use file_content  instead of f in your search.

Use group() to capture

Output:

```
filename,name,location
file1.html, John Smith,122 Main Street
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: ```f.close()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'```

Comment: I am getting a CSV that looks like this: `filename,name,location
file1.html,"<re.Match object; span=(30, 70), match='<p><strong>Name:</strong> John Smith</p>'>",` The location isn't showing up at all.